# Java applet RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator

Tags: applet, java

I have written my first java applet and get errors when deploying it on my web server. My applet uses couple of additional jar files like javaMail `mail.jar`, `smtp.jar`, `mailapi.jar` and others. When I try to display my applet in web browser I get such info in Error Dialog:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
..
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
    ... 20 more
```

I am not very good with web applications and not sure what causes this error. From the info I assume that my applet cannot load the libraries. So how can I solve this? I have those libraries on my server in /lib directory. All other files are in main directory. My HTML file is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>TPSA Speed Test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>
<APPLET code="speedtester_pkg/AppletMain.class" archive="SpeedTester.jar" width=440     height=600></APPLET>
</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I also tried to load my applet to web browser using JNLP with the same effect. I tried to find some way to point those libraries in HTML file, but I didn't manage (tried to add another `jar` archive lines or `nativelib` in JNLP file). I also tried to add those libraries to jar file with my applet classes, but that didn't help either.

This is my code where I use javaMail (sendTestResults() method near end of the code):

```
/*
 * AppletMain.java
 */
package speedtester_pkg;

import java.awt.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class AppletMain extends javax.swing.JApplet implements PropertyChangeListener{

private ArrayList<String> customerFields;
private DataReader dataReader;
private Test test;
private FileHandler fh;
private ProgressBarTask progressBarTask;
private JTextField[] customerData;
private String speed, cpuLoad, NICspeed, testTime;
private int timeDef = 60;
    /**
 * The input file directory
 */
//    public String directory = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Pulpit\\";
public String filename = "speedtestData.txt";
/**
 * Input file should be  a simple "*.txt" file named "speedtestData.txt"
 */
public File file;
// mail sending data
/**
 * TO DO encrypt mailing data
 */
private String smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com",
        username = "myUserName",
        password = "myPassword";

private int port = 465; // TLS 587/ SSL 465


/** Initializes the applet Applet */
@Override
public void init() {
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/** This method is called from within the init() method to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    infoPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    labelLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelLinkSpeed = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelProcessorLoad = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelNIC = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    buttonStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jProgressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    formPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    buttonSend = new javax.swing.JButton();
    labelForm = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    infoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    commentText = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    labelTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelTitle.setText("Link Speed Test");

    labelLinkSpeed.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    labelLinkSpeed.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    labelProcessorLoad.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    labelProcessorLoad.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    labelNIC.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelNIC.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    buttonStart.setText("Start");
    buttonStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonStartActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("Szybkość łącza:");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText("Obciążenie procesora:");

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setText("Szybkość karty sieciowej:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout infoPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(infoPanel);
    infoPanel.setLayout(infoPanelLayout);
    infoPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, infoPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(labelLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(labelLinkSpeed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 146, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(labelProcessorLoad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 146, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(labelNIC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 146, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addComponent(labelTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, infoPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(352, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(buttonStart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    infoPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, infoPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(labelTitle)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(labelLinkSpeed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(labelProcessorLoad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(labelNIC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(6, 6, 6))
                .addGroup(infoPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addComponent(labelLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(buttonStart)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout formPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(formPanel);
    formPanel.setLayout(formPanelLayout);
    formPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        formPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 417, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    formPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        formPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 127, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel8.setText("Uwagi:");

    buttonSend.setText("Wyślij");
    buttonSend.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonSendActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    labelForm.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14));
    labelForm.setText("Formularz:");

    infoLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    infoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    infoLabel.setText("Kliknij przycisk \"Start\" aby rozpocząć test");

    commentText.setColumns(20);
    commentText.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane.setViewportView(commentText);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 437, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGap(0, 437, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 417, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(formPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(infoLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 417, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 417, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(infoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(labelForm)
                .addComponent(buttonSend, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 572, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGap(0, 572, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(infoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jProgressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(infoLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(labelForm)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(formPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(buttonSend)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

public void createGUI()
{
    try {
        dataReader = new DataReader(this);
        dataReader.read();
        customerFields = dataReader.getCustomerFields();
        testTime = String.valueOf(dataReader.getTestTime());
        initComponents();
        generateCustomerForm();
        test = new Test(this, dataReader.getDownloadURLs(), dataReader.getTestTime());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

private void buttonStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
    infoLabel.setText("Poczekaj do końca testu...");
    progressBarTask = new ProgressBarTask(this);
            infoLabel.setText("progress bar");
    progressBarTask.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    progressBarTask.execute();
    Thread testThread = new Thread(this.test);
    testThread.start();
    System.out.println("Test thread \"" + testThread.getName() + "\" started.");
}                                           

private void buttonSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        sendTestResults();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppletMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}                                          

private void generateCustomerForm() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    //correcting auto-generated layout
    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11));
    labelProcessorLoad.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    labelLogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage(getDocumentBase(), "orange.jpeg")));

    //gereate JLabels and JTextFields read from file
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    formPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    customerData = new JTextField[customerFields.size()];

    for(int i=0; i<customerFields.size(); i++)
    {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(customerFields.get(i));
        l.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11));
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=i;
        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        formPanel.add(l, gbc);

        JTextField t = new JTextField();
        t.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11));
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=i;
        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        formPanel.add(t, gbc);
        customerData[i] = t;
    }

}

/**
 * Invoked when task's progress property changes.
 */
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) {
        int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
        jProgressBar.setValue(progress);
    }
}

public void setLabelProcessorLoad(String text)
{
    labelProcessorLoad.setText(text);
}

public void setLabelLinkSpeed(String text)
{
    labelLinkSpeed.setText(text);
}

public void setLabelNIC(String text)
{
    labelNIC.setText(text);
}

public JProgressBar getProgressBar()
{
    return jProgressBar;
}

public JButton getButtonStart()
{
    return buttonStart;
}

public Test getTest()
{
    return this.test;
}

public void setNICspeed(String NICspeed) {
    this.NICspeed = NICspeed;
}

public void setCpuLoad(String cpuLoad) {
    this.cpuLoad = cpuLoad;
}

public void setSpeed(String speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public JLabel getInfoLabel() {
    return infoLabel;
}
/**
 * Prepares e-mail message for sending via google SMTP protocol with SSL
 */
private void sendTestResults() throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
        }
    });

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    //Setting message fields
    Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(dataReader.getMail(), "SpeedTest crew");
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    message.setSubject("SpeedTest");

    message.setText(prepareMailText(), "UTF8");

    Transport.send(message);
    infoLabel.setText("Wiadomość z wynikami testu została wysłana pomyślnie");
    System.out.println("Mail sent.");
}

/**
 * Gets all test results and customer data and prepares mail content
 * @return the content of e-mail body
 */
private String prepareMailText()
{
    String messageContentHeader = "Prędkość pobierania\t" + "Obciążenie procesora\t" +
            "Szybkość łącza karty sieciowej\t" + "Czas trwania testu\t";
    String messageContent = speed + "\t"+ cpuLoad + "\t" + NICspeed + "\t" + testTime + "\t";

    for(int j=0;j<customerData.length;j++)
    {
        messageContentHeader += customerFields.get(j) + "\t";
        messageContent += customerData[j].getText() + "\t";
    }
    messageContentHeader += "Uwagi";
    messageContent += commentText.getText();
    String messageText = messageContentHeader + "\n" + messageContent;
    return messageText;
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton buttonSend;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonStart;
private javax.swing.JTextArea commentText;
private javax.swing.JPanel formPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel infoLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel infoPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelForm;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelLinkSpeed;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelLogo;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelNIC;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelProcessorLoad;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelTitle;
// End of variables declaration                   



}
```

I also had a problem with other libraries like Sigar.jar, but I suppose it will solve similarly.

Somebody has good tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary to add the Jar containing the `javax.mail` packages to the run-time class-path of the applet.  To achieve that (one way is to) put that Jar in the same place `SpeedTester.jar` and change the archive attribute from:

```html
archive="SpeedTester.jar"
```

..to:

```html
archive="SpeedTester.jar,mail.jar"
```

### Update 1

Change the entire applet element:

#### From

```html
<APPLET 
    code="speedtester_pkg/AppletMain.class" 
    archive="SpeedTester.jar" 
    width=440     
    height=600>
</APPLET>
```

#### To

```html
<APPLET 
    code="speedtester_pkg.AppletMain" 
    archive="SpeedTester.jar,mail.jar" 
    width=440     
    height=600>
</APPLET>
```

Presuming the package of the applet class is `speedtester_pkg` and the applet is named `AppletMain`.  The code attribute should be the fully qualified name of the applet class, not the path/file name.

### Update 2

The above advice re. the `mail.jar` does not account for classes that are referenced from within the `Test`, `DataReader` or `ProgressBarTask` (or the classes they load).  'Rinse and repeat' that advice for adding extra APIs to the run-time class-path using the archive attribute.

#### Note

It seems the other answers are referring to a web-app. that is entirely server-side.  For such a web-app., putting Jars into the `lib` makes sense.  OTOH an applet can only access a Jar that is available by copy/pasting the URL of the Jar into the browser address bar and hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

In fact doing just that, using a combination of the code-base & href of the Jar, is a good 'acid test' of whether an applet will be able to access the archive.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I did that and it worked with the mail.jar, but now applet throws similar exception with sigar class: 'code' Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission sigar.nativeLogging read)
'code' even, when I add sigar.jar to archive path: 'code'<APPLET 
 code="speedtester_pkg.AppletMain" 
 archive="SpeedTester.jar,mail.jar,sigar.jar" 
 width=440 
 height=600>
</APPLET>
'code'

Comment: Ah.  The dreaded `AccessControlException`.  That is an easily answerable, but quite separate, question. ;)  Why not mark this one as answered & ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the JAR with `javax.mail.Authenticator`

You can use the FindJar site to figure out what the name of the JAR is and where to download it.  Google for it; it's worth knowing about.

You might be missing others as well.  Keep adding JARs to your app's WEB-INF/lib until those CNF exceptions go away.

Answer (score 0):

Missing JARs (mail.jar in your case) is the primary reason for any ClassNotFound exception. Place it in your app server's **lib** directory to resolve this.